# Where to include data sanitization. Inside or outside object functions?

Tags: php, oop, sanitization

I'm doing a PHP OO project and long been thinking about, where to put variable sanitization. Make the object methods all around, ready to rumble and do the sanitization or give the coder some freedom and space for negligence to sanitize all the data by himself and make the functions dumb executors?

Which one is the preferred OO conform way?

```
class something
{

    public function getCategoryByCID($cid)
    {
        if (!is_array($cid))
            $cid = (array)$cid;

        $cid = implode("','", $cid);
        $cid = sanitizemeHARD($cid);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM cat WHERE (cat_cid IN ('$cid'))";
        return $db->q($sql);
    }

}


$c = new something();
$c->getCategoryByCID($_GET['cid']);

OR

$c = new something();

$cid = sanitizemeHARD($_GET['cid']);
$c->getCategoryByCID($cid); //Of course in this case, the func doesn't have sanitization built in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a question of policy that you set for the whole project.
I would prefer following the rule "Filter upon receiving" - i.e. at the point where external data is acquired.

This would avoid double-sanitizing in each object/method the data might pass through, and also makes easier to check the whole code for correct filtering.

So, in your example - the second case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the coder take care of the sanitization because you do not know what type of value is expected, the coder knows.

But with your example, you try to sanitize for string concatenation in SQL statements. You should not do that, use prepared queries instead.

Comment: OK, your take is: outside. Do not care about the example.

Comment: No, my take is: give the coder easy to use tools to do the validation. Don't try to do it for them.

Answer (score 1):

First case (sanitize inside function) is better, I think. Because:

1. You will be absolutely sure that data is sanitized. Otherwise you will need to check **each** way where from data can be passed.
2. Sanitizing is CPU-time, and some data can be not used (in `if`s, for example), so you will sanitize data only when it's really necessary, you will save your CPU time :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go with inside:

1)You may need to open a Db connection to sanitize, and maybe you do that inside your function. (But it depends on your design).

2) The process is automatized. You don't need to take care manually every time of sanitization. The only time you forget to sanitize, could be a big problem.